# Changing background image on rollover with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, rollover

I am trying to make my div change its background on `rollover`, but I would like to avoid using JavaScript.

Here is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">

 .rollover a {     
        display : block;
        width : 200px;
        height : 200px;             
        background-image : url( image1 ); 
    }

    .rollover a:hover { 
        display : block;
        width : 200px;
        height : 200px;
        background-image : url( image2 ); 
    }

</style>

<div class="rollover"> 
    <a href="/site">sitelink</a> 
</div>
```

It works fine but the image is cropped.

I need to show the full image in size 200px, 200px.

Comment: Off-topic comment - you don't need to re-declare the `display`, `width` and `height` properties on the `:hover` state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) and also always a good idea to use [background-repeat](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) too

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Since only one thing changes on the hover state, the second selector can simply be `.rollover a:hover { background-image : url( image2 ); }`

Comment: Yes, i am really new to the site. Okey i understand.

Answer (score 1):

This example work fine for me but problem is when i want to use another one rollover image. Problem is with positioning second rollover image. I tried change display : **block**; to **inline-block** but it did not help.

```
 .rollover1 a {     
            display : block;
            width : 200px;
            height : 200px;             
            background-image : url( image1 ); 
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            margin-left: 150px;           
            margin-top: 100px; 
        }
     .rollover1 a:hover { 
        display : block;
        width : 200px;
        height : 200px;
        background-image : url( image2 ); 
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-left: 150px;          
        margin-top: 100px; 
    }
```

**Edit:**  I got it. I forgot define `position:absolute;`